# Linux Device Driver can i2c transaction be pre-empted?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

The code that I'm having trouble with is trying to write a big register table to a i2c slave device hanging off the processor. The table has around 200 register settings. The steps are:

1. Grab mutex allocated for this specific i2c client (slave device)
2. For each slave device register to write to: set the page register by doing `i2c_smbus_write_byte_data`, then write to the actual register with data using `i2c_smbus_write_byte_data` again.
3. Repeat 2. for the whole table
4. Release mutex

In our application code, we find that every once in a while (1 out of 5?) applying the entire table fails. The `i2c_smbus_write_byte_data` fails sometimes halfway through the table, sometimes a third. Sometimes it fails at setting the page register, sometimes at writing the data at the actual register.

`i2c_smbus_write_byte_data` return code is -EIO. The fault register on the slave device indicates "SMBus Timeout".

The strange thing is that I have a software tool that calls the exact same API I exposed. Running two instances of this tool concurrently using a bash script repeatedly (no delays) for 1000 cycles produces no errors. Only the application code can reproduce the issue. The application code only runs once so I think it's much less stressful than my stress test script.

I think the difference is that the tool runs with root user privilege whereas application code is lower priority?

So my questions are:

1. Anyone encountered this issue before with random failing I2C transactions?
2. Can a call to `i2c_smbus_write_byte_data` be pre-empted in kernel space? Meaning a i2c transaction is started but the processor does something else, leaving the slave hanging?

Thanks, appreciate any help.

Comment: Priority and privilege are independent attributes. Privilege shouldn't have anything to do with your failure rates. Priority could be an issue. The tool is probably more robust, and might actually be retrying on failures, or it might be running slower or faster.  The best way to debug this is to stick a probe on the clock and data lines and record a scope buffer full of traces up the point of failure.  Compare that with "normal" operation witnessed when you run the tool.

Comment: Are you certain that all users of that bus go through your mutex?

Comment: Anything inside the critical section can't be preempted in non-RT kernels. Also check datasheets how you program your device, it might be supporting block transfers. Besides that, you need to carefully check SDA hold values for I2C being operational. I2C is not so reliable bus, I would rather consider to switch to SPI or USB if you can.